# Windows scheduled task not running

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I have several SQL server backups on a server. I have created a batch file which then copies these to network drives. These are mapped to the server, and it works properly.

Now, I've created a scheduled task to do this. If I select "run the task when logged in", I can test the task. It works fine. However I cannot test it with the other option "run task if logged in or not".

I've read that testing this task is not possible manually. However the task runs when we log off the server automatically.

This is not happening.

Comment: The task runs when you log off the server automatically?  Did you mean to say this?  The title of the question suggests this isn't working.

Comment: @Paul I didn't understand it either, see my edit history. Ravi, what exactly is happening? Is the task *not* running and do you want it to run?

Comment: I am sorry, if i was not clear. It is not working. Many blogs say, that i need to log out for "run task if logged in or not" option to work. However, that doesn't work.